# Add new column in a dataframe based on a condition on the content of another column in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

def scrap_hrefs(url,baseUrl):
    resp = requests.get(url, headers= header)
    respData = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')     
    allHrefs = respData.select('[href]')
    
    return allHrefs, baseUrl
    
    
def get_hrefs(allHrefs, baseUrl):
    for i in range(0,len(allHrefs)):
        if allHrefs[i]['href'].startswith('/'):
            allHrefs[i]= baseUrl + allHrefs[i]['href']
        else:
            allHrefs[i]= allHrefs[i]['href']
            
    return allHrefs

def clean_hrefs(allHrefs): 
    links = {'links' : allHrefs}
    df = pd.DataFrame(links).drop_duplicates()
    df = df[df['links'].str.contains('financial|investors|investor|Investors|Investor|INVESTORS|INVESTOR|relations|relation|Relations|Relation|report|filings|news|media')]
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if df[i]['links'].str.find('financial|investors|investor|Investors|Investor|INVESTORS|INVESTOR|relations|relation|Relations|Relation|report|filings')!= -1:
            df[i]['segments'] = df['Finance']
        else:
            continue
    
    return df
    
def store_hrefs(df):       
    df.to_csv("testing.csv", index=False)
   
    
def run_scraper(url,baseUrl) :
    store_hrefs(clean_hrefs(get_hrefs(*scrap_hrefs(url, baseUrl))))
     
    
run_scraper('https://www.example.com/','https://www.example.com')
```

In clean_hrefs() function, I want to get the first link from the data frame, check if it's content has the word 'finance, investors, ir, report, filings'. If it does, create another column called 'segments' and assign it id 'FINANCE'.
But it's giving an error. **KeyError: 0**
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: no need for `range` here use `.loc` with `str.contains` i.e `df.loc[df['links'].str.contains(...)==True, 'segments'] = 'finance'`

Comment: thanks! this works. But what if I have multiple conditions? I did the following : 

 df.loc[df['links'].str.contains('financial')==True, 'segmentID'] = 'finance'
    df.loc[df['links'].str.contains('investors|investor|Investors|Investor|INVESTORS|INVESTOR|relations|relation|Relations|Relation|report|filings')==True, 'segmentID'] = 'investors'

Comment: It's only performing the task for 'investors'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set column to another one by mask, similar like filtration, if no matching get missing values:

```
mask = df['links'].str.contains('financial|investors|investor|Investors|Investor|INVESTORS|INVESTOR|relations|relation|Relations|Relation|report|filings')
df.loc[mask, 'segments'] = 'Finance'
```

working like:

```
df['segments'] = np.where(mask, 'Finance', np.nan)
```

EDIT:

If want set multiple values you can specify new values in dictionary and then set column `segments` like:

```
d = {'INVESTOR':'financial|investors|investor|Investors|Investor|INVESTORS|INVESTOR|relations|relation|Relations|Relation|report|filings',
     'NEWS':'news|media'}

for k, v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['links'].str.contains(v, na=False), 'segmentID'] = k
```

Comment: I pasted the following code :

mask = ['links'].str.contains('financial|investors|investor|Investors|Investor|INVESTORS|INVESTOR|relations|relation|Relations|Relation|report|filings')

df.loc[mask, 'segments'] = df['Finance']

after the line : 

    df = df[df['links'].str.contains('financial|investors|investor|Investors|Investor|INVESTORS|INVESTOR|relations|relation|Relations|Relation|report|filings|news|media')]


It's giving me this error  :

'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @SoumyaPandey Sorry, I forget for `df`, need `df['links']`

Comment: Yeah, I figured. It's okay. But even after putting df'[links'] its giving an error : 
KeyError: 'Finance'

Comment: @SoumyaPandey - Do you want set string `Finance` ? answer was edited.

Comment: `def clean_hrefs(allHrefs): 
    links = {'links' : allHrefs}
    df = pd.DataFrame(links).drop_duplicates()
    df = df[df['links'].str.contains('financial|investors|investor|Investors|Investor|INVESTORS|INVESTOR|relations|relation|Relations|Relation|report|filings|news|media')]
    if df.loc[df['links'].str.contains('financial|investors|investor|Investors|Investor|INVESTORS|INVESTOR|relations|relation|Relations|Relation|report|filings')==True]:
        df['segmentID'] = 'INVESTOR'
    elif df.loc[df['links'].str.contains('news|media')==True]:
        df['segmentID'] = 'NEWS' `

Comment: Made these changes to the function. 
I want the links that contain keywords like finance, investors... to get a segmentID 'INVESTORS' 
and the links that have words like news and media to get a segmentID 'NEWS'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227576/discussion-between-soumya-pandey-and-jezrael).